# Maven exec-maven-plugin and maven-resources-plugin not running, not sure why

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, pom.xml, exec-maven-plugin, maven-resources-plugin

I have added a couple of new plugins to a maven `pom.xml` file.

I have not been able to figure out why `exec-maven-plugin` and  `maven-resources-plugin` they aren't running when I issue the command: `mvn install`. The other maven plugins do execute as expected.

When I run `mvn exec:exec`, `exec-maven-plugin` does indeed get run.

I have tried using a number of different phases, to no avail.

What am I doing wrong here, and what should I try?

---

Here is the relevant section of my maven file

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>build-spa-bower</id>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>bower</executable>
                    <arguments>install</arguments>
                    <workingDirectory>src/main/spa</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>build-spa-grunt</id>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>bower</executable>
                    <arguments>install</arguments>
                    <workingDirectory>src/main/spa</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>resource-spa</id>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/spa</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <directory>src/main/spa/dist</directory>
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <!-- ... -->
</plugins>
```

---

EDIT:

found answer for exec plugin, but not yet for resources plugin.

The exec plugin requires a goal in order to trigger

adding `<goals><goal>exec</goal></goals>` to each `<execution>` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put your configuration in an `<execution/>` you need to specify which goals need to run in this execution.

For plugins that are linked to a phase by default, you can also specify the configuration outside the `<executions/>` and that configuration will be used during the default phases of that plugin.

Comment: Ha, came up with the answer at the same time! +1 and check to you. Yes, specifying the goals did the trick. Am a newbie at maven, pardon the beginner question! (My own solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22393391/194982 )

Comment: ... and if you could, I would appreciate it if you could answer a follow up question I have on exec-maven-plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22393785/exec-maven-plugin-says-cannot-run-specified-program-even-though-it-is-on-the-pa

Answer (score 0):

Found answers:

The exec plugin requires a goal in order to trigger.

Add `<goals><goal>exec</goal></goals>` to each `<execution>`.

The resources plugin problem was fixed similarly.

Add `<goals><goal>copy-resources</goal></goals>` to each `<execution>`.

These did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Also

```
<phase>prepare-package</phase>
```

is compulsory.