# exec-maven-plugin says cannot run specified program, even though it is on the PATH

Tags: java, node.js, maven, path, maven-plugin

*Edit 20140716*:

[Solution found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22395703/194982)

tl;dr = exec-maven-plugin does **not** recognise `.cmd` files, but only `.bat` files, as executable scripts. Rename `grunt.cmd --> grunt.bat`, `bower.cmd --> bower.bat`, etc. as a workaround.

---

Having done `npm install -g grunt-cli` on my system, `grunt` is most certainly on the `PATH`

When I run `maven install` however, this doesn't seem to register.

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec 
    (build-spa-bower) on project foobar: Command execution failed. 
    Cannot run program "grunt" (in directory "C:\workspace\foobar\src\main\spa"): 
    CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: 
    Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec 
    (build-spa-bower) on project foobar: Command execution failed.
```

Just to be sure, in the same terminal, I have executed this

```
cd C:\workspace\foobar\src\main\spa
grunt build
```

... in the same terminal as I issued the maven command above, and grunt executes just fine.

Does `exec-maven-plugin` use the `PATH` environment variable, or does it need to be told that this executable exisst in some other way?

---

EDIT:

This [documentation](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#executable) suggests that executables on `PATH` should be found, so it stumps me further.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to bguiz' answer, which would be the best solution, I've created a workaround using Maven profiles, bypassing the problem.

This is a temporary solution, until the maven-exec-plugin's bug gets fixed.

Please upvote the bug report here: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MEXEC-118

**Edit:** The bug is resolved, you can point to 1.4-SNAPSHOT to fix it.

```
<project>
(...)
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>grunt-exec-windows</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>Windows</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>grunt-default</id>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <executable>cmd</executable>
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument>/C</argument>
                                        <argument>grunt</argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </configuration>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>exec</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: I've tried to use this command and my maven responds with `Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)`  any ideas how to get some more debugging info from maven?

Answer (score 12):

I dug into the source code of `exec-maven-plugin` and found this snippet.

From the source of `ExecMojo#getExecutablePath`:

```
    CommandLine toRet;
    if ( OS.isFamilyWindows() && exec.toLowerCase( Locale.getDefault() ).endsWith( ".bat" ) )
    {
        toRet = new CommandLine( "cmd" );
        toRet.addArgument( "/c" );
        toRet.addArgument( exec );
    }
    else
    {
        toRet = new CommandLine( exec );
    }
```

I compared this to another plugin that ran grunt tasks from maven, and [found this](https://github.com/trecloux/yeoman-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/trecloux/yeoman/YeomanMojo.java#L90)

```
        if (isWindows()) {
            command = "cmd /c " + command;
        }
```

... and that worked for me. So essentially the latter worked because all commands in WIndows were prepended with `cmd /c`,
whereas the `exec-maven-plugin` did not, because it only did so for file ending in `.bat`.

Looking in `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm`, I see:

- `node_modules` (folder)
- `grunt` (unix script file)
- `grunt.cmd` (windows script file)

When I rename `grunt.cmd` --> `grunt.bat`, this solves the problem, and `exec-maven-plugin` is able to run this command.

(this also applies to other executables created using `npm install -g`, such as `bower` and `yo`)

Comment: Thanks for finding the cause of this problem. I've submitted a patch here, please upvote if you have the same problem! http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MEXEC-137

Comment: Apparently this issue is a duplicate of https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MEXEC-118, which isn't solved yet.

Comment: @PietvanDongen you're welcome! BTW, you might find this post interesting: [Making Maven Grunt, Windows Edition](http://blog.bguiz.com/post/79804496081/making-maven-grunt-windows-edition) - see the section "Why can’t my plugin find executables?"

Comment: I've read the post, that's how I got here in the first place :) The bug has been resolved as from version 1.4. You can point to 1.4-SNAPSHOT for now to have it fixed: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MEXEC-118

Comment: Sounded promising, but I get the same error even after renaming

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with 1.5.0 of the plugin.

The cause in my case was spaces in my user name resulting in a grunt path:
C:\Users\My name with spaces\AppData\Roaming\npm.

When I moved the contents of the npm directory to a path without spaces, it worked.

Comment: Please have a look at the other answers with upvotes to a hang about how answers shell look like and which information they should provide. Furthermore please take a look at [how do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help).